# Issue with Aviary SDK device orientation

Tags: ios, aviary

I am trying to lunch Aviary SDK photo editor in landscape mode , but it works only on iPad !! , my app crashes on iPhone due this problem :

> 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

I tried different ways but no success :

```
- (IBAction)photoEditor:(id)sender {

    [self displayEditorForImage:imageBG.image];

}


- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)imageToEdit
{
 //set device orientation 

    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setSupportedIpadOrientations:@[@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight),
     @(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ]];


    AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

none of these codes worked :

1-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ( (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) );
}
```

2-

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;;
}
```

3-

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; // add any other you want
 }



-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

//tried NO too , 
    return YES ;

  }
```

my app is running on iOS 6 , appreciate for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Aviary FAQ:

> Q: How do I change the supported orientations for the editor?
>
> A: On the iPhone form factor, the Editor is restricted to Portrait presentation only. [...]

That means what you want is impossible. The editor must run in Portrait mode.

Comment: Still crashes !! I even made a subclass and set shouldRotate to NO ! but still crashes !

Comment: @Mc.Lover That's intented behavior. The SDK just cannot run in landscape mode. You have to add `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` to the supported orientations.

Comment: @SulthanIs Is there anyway to uncheck Portrait in supported orientations ? because my app runs in only Landscape mode if I check this option screen rotates and `shouldAutoRotate` and other screen rotation  lock codes won't work !!!!